# My controller return correct data but datatable doesnt vizualize it

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, datatables

I have a very strange problem for the first time when I use Datatables. My action returns JSON response with correct data to datatable but in view I don't receive table with filled data but JSON format data. Where is the problem?

```
public class Proba
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Action is

```
 public ActionResult UserList()
    {
        var data = context.Probas.ToList();
        return Json(new { data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<MSklad.Models.Proba>


<div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: 30px;">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Нов потребител" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Register", "Account")'"  style="margin-bottom: 10px;"/>
        <table id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Id
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Name
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready( function () {
            $('#myTable').DataTable(
                {
                    "responsive": "true",
                    "ajax": {
                    "type" : "GET" ,
                    "url" : "@Url.Action("UserList","Account")" ,
                    "datatype" : "json"
                    },
                    "columns":
                    [
                        { "data": "Id" },
                        { "data": "Name"}
                    ],
                    "language": {
                        "processing": "<img src='https://gph.is/2gESFHh' />",
                        "emptytable": "No data found, You may click on <b> Add New </b> button"
                    }
                });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Response in browser

```
{"data":[{"Id":"1","Name":"ime","Age":1}]}
```

Comment: Did you try to specify "dataSrc" in ajax to tell DataTables where the data array is in the JSON structure? ajax: { ..., dataSrc: 'data'  } ... },

Comment: Why are you adding the data property in the first place? I mean, you add special code to do it (`return Json(new { data = data }, ...` instead of just `return Json(data, ...`)...

Comment: @user2250152 Yes, result is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON has a data attribute {"data":[{"Id":"1","Name":"ime","Age":1}]}. just add "dataSrc": "data"

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myTable').DataTable(
            {
                "responsive": "true",
                "ajax": {
                "type": "GET",
                "url": "@Url.Action("UserList","Account")" ,
                "datatype": "json",
                "dataSrc": "data"
            },
            "columns":
                [
                    { "data": "Id" },
                    { "data": "Name" }
                ],
            "language": {
                "processing": "<img src='https://gph.is/2gESFHh' />",
                "emptytable": "No data found, You may click on <b> Add New </b> button"
            }
        });
    });
```

In your Account Controller, create an Action method, I am naming mine Index which will take me to the View with DataTables

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Then from your View using ajax in your DataTable you will be calling another Action Method

```
    public JsonResult UserList()
    {
       var data = context.Probas.ToList();
       return Json(new { data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

You will have two Action methods, one will take you to your View and another one will return Json Data when called from the DataTable

Comment: you only have one Action method which returns the data and does not take it to the View where your DataTable is. I have updated my answer